# How to handle redirects with aws cognito federated identities

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, react-router-v4, aws-amplify

I have a SPA (Single page application) using ReactJS. 
Currently, I am allowing users to login with Facebook or Google through AWS Cognito with the Amplify console (My site is hosted with Amplify on S3).

My problem is that when a user tries to enter a page that requires login, he is then redirected to the Sign In page (Using react-router-dom v4), then when they log in, they get redirected to Facebook/Google and then redirected back to my site's home page.

I would like to return them to the page the sent them to sign in as this will cause a bad user experience for my users.

The Auth function I use is: 
Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: "Facebook" }).

How can I send them back to the page that sent them to the redirect without storing the page in my store as the session refreshes and the store is not maintained?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass your page as a custom state

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Google', customState: JSON.stringify(route)})
```

and get it back in an auth event

```
Hub.listen('auth', ({payload: {event, data}}) => {

  switch (event) {
    case 'signIn':
      user = data
      break

  case 'customOAuthState':
      route = JSON.parse(data)
      // go to route
      break;
  }
```

})